# Chaining methods in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make an animation by adding a class `pressed` then wait for 100ms then remove the class.

when I just add the class 
    `$("#" + currentColor).addClass("pressed");`
the code works fine. But when I chain the methods or write them separately none of the methods work.

```
$(".btn").on("click", function () {
    var userChosenColor = $(this).attr("id");
    animatePress(userChosenColor);
});
function animatePress(currentColor) {
    $("#" + 
currentColor).addClass("pressed").delay(100).removeClass("pressed");
}
```

I expect it to add the class `pressed` then wait 100ms then remove the class`pressed`. But it doesn't do anything. I also don't get any error report in the console

Comment: Try [`:active`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the delay method only delays *effects*, such as `fadeIn`. It will not delay adding or removing classes. You should use setTimeout for that.

```
$(".btn").on("click", function () {
    var userChosenColor = $(this).attr("id");
    animatePress(userChosenColor);
});

function animatePress(currentColor) {
    $("#" + currentColor).addClass("pressed");
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        $("#" + currentColor).removeClass("pressed");
    }, 100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [setTimeout()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) method for delaying the second action.

Your code should be like this:

```
$(".btn").on("click", function () {
    var userChosenColor = $(this).attr("id");
    animatePress(userChosenColor);
});

function animatePress(currentColor) {
   $("#" + currentColor).addClass("pressed");

   setTimeout(function(){
        $("#" + currentColor).removeClass("pressed")
    },100)

}
```